# sync two processes at some system call

Tags: linux, process, system-calls

Is it possible to synchronize two linux processes at some system calls without modifying their code?

A real world example: `v4l2-ctl` is a tool that can be used to set certain controls of a web camera. After running it to set some controls, `ffmpeg` is used to capture a movie with the camera. However, setting only some controls on it's own and resetting some other, `ffmpeg` ruins the careful adjustments made by `v4l2-ctl`.

Now it would be useful to remedy this problem without having to modify and rebuilt one or both of this tools. This would be possible if `ffmpeg` could be started, but would be suspended after it opened and configured `/dev/video0` (most likely some `ioctls` happened) and `v4l2-ctl` would be invoked then to apply the settings. After that, `ffmpeg` would be resumed and start capturing with the right settings in place.

Is this possible to track one processes io operations and suspend it on some by easy means?

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling adventurous and don't mind the performance hit of using a debug-compiled `ffmpeg`, you could conceivably start it under `gdb` and set a breakpoint after opening `/dev/video0` (or anywhere else.  You'll need the source either way.)

You could then run the binary until it hits the breakpoint, tweak `v4l2-ctl` and then tell `ffmpeg` to continue past the breakpoint.

Comment: That would have the advantage to clarifiy on what location the suspend happens. However, I thought a few `ioctls` issued give enough overview to make a clean cut. So I wonder if there is any way to intercept or stop on a plausible io operation rather then analyzing the vast code.

Comment: The problem is that even if you could observe such an event (say, with `strace`) then you wouldn't be able to react (say, by sending a `SIGSTOP`) in time: `ffmpeg` would keep right on running after the event, until it e.g. handled the signal.

Comment: `strace` looks cool. Maybe the way `strace` intercept the calls could be used to block the call itself? If such a tool exist, it could execute the system call but keep control and then suspend the process, calling a user command, and resume the process. The process would stuck at the intercepted `ioctl` while the new settings are applied this way.

Comment: This would be like a convenient version of `gdb`, that places a conditional breakpoint in `ioctl` itself and runs a user command if hit. Any process could be intercepted this way without the need of a debug build of the application itself. Maybe the tool has to tweak the shared libraries loaded to have a interruptible `ioctl` call.

Comment: This would also be cool for application testing, eg. test externally modifying a file between each possible access inside an application.